how to implement a global shared resource within the scope of a class
This question is not about the difference between class and instance variables.
I want to design my program in such a way that my main class provides global resources to modules for them to use but doesn't really need to manage them itself. The modules will orchestrate themselves. I want those modules to be able to access those shared resources without having to explicitly pass the resource to them
A simple example: In one of my classes I want to have a shared resource (in this case self.shared.
# main.py
from sub import Item

class Main():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.shared = []
        self.item1 = Item('item 1', 'car')
        self.item2 = Item('item 2', 'dog')

In the module sub I have the Item class defined
# sub.py
class Item():
    def __init__(self, name, type) -> None:
        # global shared
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        shared.append(self.name)

When an instance of Item is created I want it to be able to add it's name to something like self.shared in Main but I don't want to have to pass the resource to the item. I want it to be able to access the resource globally within the class. How can I do this?
Python 3.12

You will either need to create a shared = Main() as class attribute on Item, or otherwise import Main into sub and instantiate it there (but that would be a circular dependency), or you'll have to explicitly pass a Main instance to Item. It's usually a bad idea to have instances track themselves somewhere, so it's usually more useful to make it Main's responsibility to add any instantiated Item to a list.

Well, you could just create a 3rd module which defines a list, and both main and sub import that module, and Items add themselves to that list and Main reads from that list. That'd be a global shared resource. But that's usually not a great idea, and explicitly passing stuff around is usually better for maintenance in the long run.

If you do not wish to explicitly pass something to Item, then whatever Item is supposed to add itself to must be accessible at any time. Your Main.shared is not accessible at any time, because it only exists if and when Main gets instantiated, and Item has no idea where this is. So what you want just won't work as is.

@deceze thanks for the input. Do you mind sharing why you think explicitly passing stuff is better for maintenance? I was thinking, from the perspective of the main program, it would be less maintenance if it was less involved in the individual parts. That way they can change their implementation over time if need be without having much impact on main.

What you want is clearly defined interfaces, clearly defined "seams" between parts. You can then take these parts and put them together in various ways, as suits your needs. You can also take them apart again and put them together differently in the future. You achieve that by explicitly passing stuff around; because you can then stop passing stuff around or start passing other stuff around. — If you have some implicit magic relationship somewhere, that stops being true. Then you sometimes can't take stuff apart anymore without things breaking elsewhere.
